# Laravel controller method is getting messy

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I have a controller with a method to process a booking. The method is getting quite large and after developing a good handful of apps I realized I'm doing something wrong because many of my controllers methods are large and messy.

For example

```
function processBooking($id) {
   // validate
   // if validaton fails return errors
   // if validation pass do the following
   $booking = getDetailsFromRepository($id)
   // check if client is paying with credits
      // process booking with credits
      // update client credids
      // check if any errors with stripe and return readable message to user
   // else process booking with credit card
      // set all date for Stripe::charge
      // capture charge
      // check if any errors with stripe and return readable message to user
   // if everything went well
      // save payment in db
      // save booking
      // return success message to user
}
```

most steps are functions from repository class. The whole method is about 300 lines.

After a bit of research I came across services so I created a ProcessBookingService.php class in which I chunck all ifs and checks down to multiple functions and I reduced the controller method down to 50 lines which makes it clean and readable.

The problem is that on the old method I would return a different message back to the user based on what went wrong ex: the card was declined, not enough points, etc.

Since most of the logic happens in the Service class, on the functions that I need to return a message back to the user I set a variable with a message and return that. Now the controllers gets lots of ifs
ex:

```
$booking = $booking->process($data);

if($booking['success']) // redirect with success
else if($booking['card_declined']) // redirect with error
else if($booking['not_enough_points']) // redirect with error
else if($booking['stripe_request_error']) // redirect with error
else // unknown error on the server redirect with error
```

Is this correct from design and programming point of view? Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use exceptions to cleanly solve the problem. It could be as simple as:

```
try
{
   $bookingService->book($data);
}
catch(BookingException $e)
{
    // redirect as error, possibly using $e->getMessage()
}

// redirect as success
```

You may want to have a hierarchy of exceptions if you want to redirect to different locations. If you're using language strings for localization, you can use the error code in the redirection:

```
redirect('error_page', ['code' => $e->getCode()]);
```

Where this gets translated to something like `example.com/book/error?code=1234` and then you use the code to display the correct, localized message.